# Keep rows, even if they dont have any rows in other join table MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT `products`.*, SUM(orders.total_count) AS revenue, SUM(orders.quantity) AS qty FROM `products` 
    LEFT JOIN `orders` ON (`products`.`id` = `orders`.`product_id`) 
    WHERE (`orders`.`status` = 'delivered' OR `orders`.`status` = 'new') 
    GROUP BY `products`.`ID` ORDER BY products.ID DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

This is what I got. Currently it only grab the products which have any orders that are either delivered or new.

That WHERE statement is only for the correct calculation of SUM(orders.total_count) and SUM(orders.quantity) -

I would like to grab all the products, and if there is any orders for this product then it should look at that where statement to make sure that the order we grab are new or delivered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is change `WHERE` to `AND`.

Really, what that means is, the predicate on the "`orders.status`" column needs to be in the `ON` clause, rather than the `WHERE` clause.

In your query, that predicate is doing the equivalent of an "`orders.status IS NOT NULL`", which is going to "throw out" any of the NULL rows that were created by the LEFT JOIN.

The easiest way to think of the LEFT (OUTER) JOIN is that it's creating a dummy "orders" row to match to a "products" row, when there is no other "orders" row that matches. And that dummy row consists of all NULL values.

Comment: Great answer, thanks alot! I am having another LEFT JOIN product_reviews ON (products.id = product_reviews.product_id) <- where I am grabbing ROUND(AVG(stars)) from, but when I do this my `qty` from orders.quantity messes up and gives a number which is not true? Cant i have two lefts? Would i need to create a new question for this?

Comment: Somehow when i have a second left join it affects the first left join

Comment: @karem enclose the joins in parenthesis to force the order of evaluation

Comment: @Barranka does not help, i tried FROM ( `products` 
    LEFT JOIN `orders` ON (`products`.`id` = `orders`.`product_id`) ) LEFT JOIN product_reviews ON (products.id = product_reviews.product_id) - still gives me a false data for the orders.total_count sum and quantity

Comment: @Karem: that really sounds like a separate question. But I believe the issue you have with that second left join is that you are getting a semi-cartesian product... every order for a product is getting matched to every review for the product... so, two reviews for a product is going "double" the quantities. It's a familiar problem, with some simple solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new question for this. The term semi-cartesian is a new term for me, thanks for the explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469837/two-left-joins-gives-me-untrue-datadouble-data-with-mysql