# SQL query returns tags fields in a group_concat function more than once

Tags: mysql, sql

everyone,

I'm working on a php and mysql project and I have a SQL query that selects the topics (collections) from my DB with user info form the users table and tags that relate to every collection I use a lookup table like that:

```
select 
        `collections`.`id` as c_id
        , `collections`.`user_id` as c_user_id
        , `thumbnail`
        , left(`collections`.`description`, 81) as description
        , `collections`.`added` as c_added
        , `collections`.`views` as c_views
        , `collections`.`likes` as c_likes
        , `collections`.`title` as c_title
        , `users`.`name` as user_name
        , `users`.`avatar`
        , group_concat(`tags`.`tag_name`) as hashtags
        from collections left join collectionstags 
                    on collections.id = collectionstags.collection_id
        left join tags on 
                    tags.id = collectionstags.tag_id 
        inner join users on
                    `collections`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
        group by collections.id 
        order by `collections`.`added` DESC
        limit 0, 16;
```

It worked fine it returns the info that I need until I tried to add another left join to get the number of comments from the comments table:

```
select 
        `collections`.`id` as c_id
        , `collections`.`user_id` as c_user_id
        , `thumbnail`
        , left(`collections`.`description`, 81) as description
        , `collections`.`added` as c_added
        , `collections`.`views` as c_views
        , `collections`.`likes` as c_likes
        , `collections`.`title` as c_title
        , `users`.`name` as user_name
        , `users`.`avatar`
        , group_concat(`tags`.`tag_name`) as hashtags
        , count(`comments`.`id`) as num_comments
        from collections left join collectionstags 
                    on collections.id = collectionstags.collection_id
        left join tags on 
                    tags.id = collectionstags.tag_id 
        inner join users on
                    `collections`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        left join comments on 
                    `comments`.`collection_id` = `collections`.`id`'; 
        group by collections.id 
        order by `collections`.`added` DESC
        limit 0, 16;
```

when I added this last join it started to return every tag 16 times instead of once for example istead of returning:

```
hashtags="nature, river, trees";
```

it returns:

```
hashtags="nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, nature, trees,...ect";
```

Comment: Try to do a sub query. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469837/two-left-joins-gives-me-untrue-datadouble-data-with-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Please use  group_concat(DISTINCT(`tags`.`tag_name`)) as hashtags

Comment: Thank you but I think this will hide the problem it won't fix it.